# How to plot a graph in the specific layout in R

Tags: r, layout, igraph, network-analysis

I have been working on a project of analyzing communication within an organization using igraph in R.

I have made some communication network graphs in different layouts which are already prepared in igraph package; for examples, "nicely","star","fr","kk". 
But I'm still looking for a way to plot a graph in the layout which I specify in detail.

In detail, the specific layout is: **putting certain node "A" in the center, and then putting around node "A" other nodes which have links to node "A", and so  on.**
For an example, I want to put a boss of an organization in the center of graph and put around the boss other members who have important (as weights according frequency of communication)  communication with the boss.

But I'm not sure *whether such layout is mathematically and technically in R possible or not*.

Thank you in advance for your help!

--(added later)--

Although some of you have already responded to my question, I'm afraid my explanation of the problem was insufficient. I'm sorry.

What I want to do is similar to the "star" layout, but a bit different to that. For me, a problem of the star layout is that all nodes without a node in the center are positioned in one circle. I mean, it is that the star layout can't handle information of distances between nodes which can otherwise be handled so in the force-directed layout such as "Fruchterman and Reingold" and "Kamada-Kawai".

Let me give you an example; a normal organization which has hierarchical structure like a company. There is a boss and 14 employees. I know who communicates with whom and how often they communicate with each other. My concerns are who communicates with the boss, whom the boss communicates with and how often these communications happen. First, I want to put the boss in the center of a network graph, secondly, put around the boss some employees who have more communication with the boss than other employees, and finally, put around them the other employees who have even less or no communication with the boss. I think it would look like a spider web.

The points are that;
 **1. a central position of a certain node (such as the boss) in a graph.
 2. distances between all nodes (such as the distance between the boss and the employees) according to a frequency of communication.**
In other words, what I think I am trying to do is to position a certain node in the center in the force-directed layout graph.

But I'm neither a specialist of social network analysis or graph theory, so I'm not sure whether what I want to do is *mathematically or theoretically possible*. Moreover I'm not sure whether it is *technically possible in R* even if it is mathematically or theoretically possible.

Comment: You mention the star layout in igraph. That would do what you want if there is only one boss. Do you mean that you have multiple bosses in the structure? A hierarchy of bosses? Is there communication other than boss to employee?   I think that you need to provide an example of the type of organization you wish to plot.

Comment: You are right, G5W. Actually what I want to do is very similar to the star layout. But that is also a bit different to my ideal image. I will add in question more information about what is wrong with the star layout, so please have a look at my question later.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether there are possibilities to do with igraph, but I am sure it is possible to do this with qgraph. You could try it with a code similar to this:

```
library(qgraph)
# run the qgraph function on the correlation matrix of mtcars and store it in q1
q1 <- qgraph(cor(mtcars))
```

In q1$layout the x- and y-coordinates of the variables of the qgraph are stored. Here I first adjust the x-coordinate of the 6th variable, by taking the mean of the x-coordinates of the remaining 10 variables. Subsequently, I do the same for the y-coordinate.

```
q1$layout[6,1] <- mean(q1$layout[c(1:5,7:11),1])
q1$layout[6,2] <- mean(q1$layout[c(1:5,7:11),2])
```

and then just plot q1. It results in below plot, with the 6th "wt" variable in the middle.

[image]

You could of course opt to change other coordinates as well to make your network graph even more pretty. Also, you have many more arguments you could adjust inside the qgraph() function to make your network prettier. :) Sorry I can't provide a solution in igraph, but I hope this could be helpful as well.

Comment: Hi, Len. Thank you for your advice. I didn't know about such package. But I think a layout of your plot is similar to a "star" layout. I've already made similar graph with ggraph, giraph and igraph. What I want to do is similar to the "star" layout and your plot, but a bit different to both. I will edit my question later with more information, so please could you have a look at that later? But I appreciate your advice.

Comment: You could set the layout argument in qgraph to "spring" to apply the Früchterman Reingold algorithm. Then it applies this algorithm to all nodes in the network, and you can adjust the coordinates for the "boss" variable afterwards the same way by adjusting the x- and y-coordinates to the means for the "boss" variable. Also, there is the possibility to add constraints on the Früchterman-Reingold algorithm directly, by defining the layout.par argument. In there you can add soft and hard constraints to all coordinates. You could look up the documentation for qgraph.layout.fruchtermanreingold.